# How do I install GNU Science Library on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cygwin, gnu

Complete newbie here. I would like to install GSL and then run some C++ programs that use its functions. I would've thought this was something easily Googled for, yet although I found lots of resources, none of them worked. Two examples are:

1. [This guide](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC210/gsl/gsl.html): followed the instructions, but even the sample program wouldn't run. Visual Studio produces five errors, four of which are "unresolved external symbol [something, such as __iob_func]".
2. [This link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/): downloaded the package, downloaded Cygwin. The install guide in the package said to run the command "./configure && make && make install" and it should install, and the command ran without problems; however afterwards when I tried to run a trial program in Cygwin, I get errors of the kind "undefined reference to 'gsl_rng_env_setup'" which I'm interpreting as GNU Science Library still not having been installed properly (or at least Cygwin doesn't know where to find it).
3. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGSW5h8i_UU) which was hard to follow since it's in French, and still didn't work because when I tried to generate the solution (3:25 into the video) I got error messages.

I've downloaded all sorts of packages, installed all sorts of programs, and I still can't get it to work. Anyone help? If possible I'd prefer to use Visual Studio since I find the environment a lot easier to use than Cygwin's command line.

Comment: It is difficult to mix `Visual-Studio` with `cygwin`. I suggest you to use one or the other. For your info GSL is already available as `cygwin` package

Comment: I prefer Visual Studio, but don't mind Cygwin. Unfortunately installing GSL as a Cygwin package still didn't work; I get "undefined reference to 'gsl_rng_env-setup' errors as well. Googling for that says I need to use something like "gcc main.cpp -lgsl", but that also doesn't work: I get "undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char" errors ...